# How to find week Number based on current date and what are the dates in that week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find out Week Number based on current date and what are the dates in that week.

Let say example, Current date is 27-Dec-2020, then I need to find out week no i.e. 53 and what are dates i.e. 28-Dec-2020, 29-Dec-2020....03-Jan-2021.

My expected output columns would be:

```
WeekNo Date Day
```

Comment: Its worrying you are using SQL Server 2008 when that is completely out of support.

Comment: I would suggest getting a calendar table.

Comment: You need to explain what *you* mean by "week number"?  What rules are you using?  Is this the ISO week number, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @date date = '30-Dec-2020'; --'20210101'

select @date as _date, 
    datepart(iso_week, @date) as isoweek, 
    --iso week starts on previous monday. weekday of monday is always 2 when accounting for @@datefirst
    dateadd(day, -(7-2+datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst, @date)))%7, @date) as isoweekstartdate,
    --isoweekenddate(inclusive) = add 6 days to isoweekstartdate
    dateadd(day, 6, dateadd(day, -(7-2+datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst, @date)))%7, @date)) as isoweekenddate;


select
    datepart(iso_week, @date) as isoweek,
    dateadd(day, n.num, dateadd(day, -(7-2+datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, @@datefirst, @date)))%7, @date)) as isoweekdate
from
(
values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
) as n(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple Loop

```
    DECLARE @date DATE, @WeekNo TINYINT, @Start TINYINT,@End TINYINT, @StartDate DATE,@EndDate DATE,  @Cdate DATE
    
SET @date='27-DEC-2020'
    
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,-7,@date)
    set @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY,7,@date)
    
    SET @WeekNo = DATEPART(WEEK,@date)
    
    SET @Start = 1
    SET @End = DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)
    
    DECLARE @dates TABLE(WeekNo TINYINT, [Date] DATE, [Day] VARCHAR(20))
    
    WHILE(@Start <=@End)
    BEGIN
        SET @Cdate = DATEADD(DAY,@Start,@StartDate)
        IF DATEPART(WEEK,@Cdate)=@WeekNo
            INSERT @dates VALUES(@WeekNo, @Cdate, DATENAME(WEEKDAY , @Cdate))
    
        SET @Start = @Start + 1
    END
    
    SELECT * FROM @dates
```